# How to animate a ball with fake physics from top down viewing angle

Tags: 2d, projectile-physics, game-maker-studio-2

I am making a 2D American football game (similar to retro bowl) in Game Maker: Studio 2, and its main perspective is in 2D. I want to animate a ball that moves in a parabola and can interact with other objects as if it were in 3d (for instance, bounce off the ground, or bounce off the players onto the ground).[image]
I have not tried anything yet, and any suggestions are useful.

Comment: [I answered a similar question on StackOverflow a while back, which might have some useful leads for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38757336/3064164). See also: [Need help projecting 2D projectile motion in 2.5D/isometric 2D game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/188983/39518).

Comment: @DMGregory yes, but what I have trouble with is figuring out how to get the ball to bounce off players and collision objects